# data.table, Binary search with numeric key?

Tags: r, data.table

From the example(data.table)

we have the following:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
setkey(DT,x)

DT["a"] # binary search.
```

Is is possible to perform such a task if the key is numeric? Say

```
setkey(DT,y)
```

Comment: Arun is working at better vignettes: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944 He'd welcome input from you if you feel something is missing in them.

Comment: Actually this question was asked many times already, and a simple Google search returns many variations of it. Take a look on @Aruns answer on the link dupe.

Comment: @Roland Thanks I'll keep that in mind for the vignette and  David I guess I was locked on the help in R and SO.

Comment: The linked dupe is an answer on SO. Did you take a look there?

Comment: I didn't look close enough... . I'll keep the question in case it might help pointing to the orginal question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course:

```
setkey(DT,y)
DT[.(3)]
#   x y v
#1: a 3 2
#2: b 3 5
#3: c 3 8
```